# Declaring variable in 'if' statement causes problem

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a rubic cube in Python 3. I am making the `flip` function now.

```
def flip(topSide, frontSide, row, column, direction):
if (direction == "right"):
    if (topSide == 1):

       if (frontSide == 2):
           a = cube[1][row - 1][:]
           cube[1][row-1][:] = cube[2][row-1][:]
           cube[2][row - 1][:] = cube[3][row - 1][:]
           cube[3][row - 1][:] = cube[4][row - 1][:]
           cube[4][row - 1][:] = a
           print(a)
```

I defined the faces as numbers. Here they are:

```py
green = 1
red = 2
yellow = 3
orange = 4
white = 5
blue = 6
```

When I delete `cube[1][row-1][:] = cube[2][row-1][:]` line, `a` is `[2,2,2]`. But if I don't delete that line `a` is `[3,3,3]`. I defined the `a` variable before I change it but, yet, it changes. Is there any way to define that variable `a` as what it supposed to be?

If you don't understand my question, don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: What is the type of `cube`? Is it a list of lists or numpy ndarray?

Answer (score 0):

Let me demonstrate it for you:

```py
import numpy as np
cube = np.random.randint(1, 7, size=(3, 3, 3))

"""
cube is
array([[[1, 4, 2],
        [5, 6, 3],
        [3, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 1],
        [5, 1, 2],
        [5, 1, 3]],

       [[3, 2, 2],
        [4, 2, 2],
        [5, 6, 2]]])
"""

row = 1
a = cube[1][row - 1][:]
print(a) #  outputs: array([2, 2, 1])

cube[1][row-1][:] = [10, 10, 10]
print(a)  # outputs: array([10, 10, 10])
```

This behaviour is because of when you run `a = cube[1][row - 1][:]`, the reference of `cube[1][row - 1][:]` is being assigned to variable `a`. Reference means, you know, the address in the memory. So if `cube[1][row-1][:]` is changed, `a` is changed as well. Because they are referencing the same address in the memory.

You need to assign its value instead of address. One of the solutions is using [`np.copy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html):

```py
a = np.copy(cube[1][row - 1][:])
print(a)  # outputs: array([2, 2, 1])

cube[1][row-1][:] = [10, 10, 10]
print(a)  #  still outputs: array([2, 2, 1])
```

Comment: Thank you too much, it did worked. But I was wondering that is it about NumPy or Python?

Comment: You're welcome. It's about Python, and nearly all other programming languages too. It may be confusing if you don't have experience with lower level languages like C or Java. But start with here: https://www.quora.com/Are-arguments-passed-by-value-or-by-reference-in-Python